# Add shape to existing group throws an exception in MS visio

Tags: visio, internal

I am using MS Visio 2013 Standard, and following these steps:

- 1: Draw a horizontal line, i.e: `BeginX:6 mm EndX:14 mm  BeginY:64 mm EndY:64 mm`
- 2: Convert shape to the group, i.e got new group shape
- 3: Draw one more horizontal line: `BeginX:16 mm EndX:24 mm  BeginY:64 mm EndY:64 mm`
- 4: Select new group shape (from step 2) and select step 3 shape: Home -> Add to Group

I am getting an exception

> visio internal error #2912
>
> Action: 1053 Add to group
>
> First try closing and reopening the file. Next try restarting visio

My question is: is this a Visio bug?

Answer (score 0):

The file is probably corrupt. Try copying first only the shapes of interest in a newly created drawing. If it works, copy the other shapes as well.

Comment: Actually file is not corrupted if I change any one line vertical Height(ex Step1 Line: BeginY:64.001 mm EndY:64.001 mm) it works properly.

Comment: sorry ,no it did not worked. I guess it is divide by zero exception